# Generic factory method with sub generic types

Tags: c#, generics

I have a type InterfaceExecuter defined with a Enter and a Exit type, both are struct.
In another class, I want to create a method which instantiate classes that implements my interface, something like this:

```
 public T<TEntry, TExit> Initiate<T<TEntry, TExit>>()
        where T: InterfaceExecuter<TEntry, TExit>, new()
        where TEntry:struct
        where TExit:struct
    {
        return new T<TEntry, TExit>();
    }
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'are almost there, just define the return type `(T)` as generic argument.

With this constraing `T: InterfaceExecuter<TEntry, TExit>` you have already defined the structure of the generic type `T` so you don't need to explicitly use the generic arguments when you instantiate it (the compiler won't allow it also)

```
public T Initiate<T, TEntry, TExit>()
            where T: InterfaceExecuter<TEntry, TExit>, new()
            where TEntry:struct
            where TExit:struct
        {
            return new T();
        }
```

Comment: Ow sure! But, do I need to call the method like this? this.Initiate<ConcreteExecuter<T1,T2>,T1, T2>() In these case I should pass struct type two times, one time for ConcreteExecutor and another for Initiate method. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, you will need to supply TEntry and TExit in both places.